# Can't start Tomcat server in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

when i am trying to start tomcat server(8.5.39) in eclipse oxygen there is an error showing:

> Error:could not create java virtual machine. Error:a fatal exception has occurred.program will exit."
>    After 40-50s there is pop up message with:" 'Starting Tomcat v8.5 Server at Localhost' has encountered a problem.

In Console Area there is a message:

> "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.39\endorsed is not supporting.Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular will be supporting via the concept of upgradeable modules."

When I am start Tomcat server from `startup.bat` file in the bin folder, he started successfully without any problem. I want to start Tomcat server from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likley affected by [Bug 507338 - Java 9 support not well integrated with Tomcat webserver (/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/endorsed is not supported)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507338).

Eclipse Oxygen has only beta support for Java 9, if you plan to use Java 9 upgrade to newer version of Eclipse or at least update the [Web Tools Platform plugin to 3.9.1aRC2a](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=507338#c22).

Comment: Unless you are still using Java 9 specifically, you should update to the current release (2019-03) where this is also addressed for Java 10, 11, and beyond.